# Language server semantic tokens

Tags: visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

In the language server protocol specification, the semantic tokens response has a data field that is an array of integers for the tokens.

```
export interface SemanticTokens {
    /**
     * The actual tokens.
     */
    data: uinteger[];
}
```

In all the samples, semantic tokens are done client side with a SemanticTokensBuilder that secifies a line and column range for each token type. How do you do that server side? When VSCode sends the "textDocument/semanticTokens/full" method, what does the language server send back?

Answer (score 5):

It's perhaps easiest to explain by looking at example. This example is adapted from https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-17/#textDocument_semanticTokens.

Suppose your file had the contents `\n\n     foo  bars\n\n  bazzled\n`, i.e. rendered with whitespace it would look like this:

```
     foo  bars

  bazzled
```

This has three tokens at the following positions (using 0-indexing):

1. `foo`, at line 2, char 5
2. `bars`, at line 2, char 10
3. `bazzled`, at line 5, char 2

Here's one possible valid `data` that the server could respond with:

```
// 1st token,  2nd token,  3rd token
[  2,5,3,0,3,  0,5,4,1,0,  3,2,7,2,0 ]
```

This is just a compressed form of the following info:

```
[ { deltaLine: 2, deltaStartChar: 5, length: 3, tokenType: 0, tokenModifiers: 3 },  // first token
  { deltaLine: 0, deltaStartChar: 5, length: 4, tokenType: 1, tokenModifiers: 0 },  // second token
  { deltaLine: 3, deltaStartChar: 2, length: 7, tokenType: 2, tokenModifiers: 0 }   // third token
]
```

That is, each group of 5 contiguous elements corresponds to one token. These 5 elements have the following meaning, in order:

1. `deltaLine`: the line difference between this token and the previous
2. `deltaStartChar`: either the start character difference between this token and the previous (if the previous is on the same line), or just the start character of this token (if the previous is on a different line)
3. `length`: the length of this token
4. `tokenType`: index into the token type legend
5. `tokenModifiers`: bit flags for token modifiers

So, for example, the second token has `deltaLine = 0`, meaning it is on the same line as the first token, and `deltaStartChar = 5` means that it starts 5 characters after the first token starts. The first token doesn't have a token before it, so its position is instead taken to be absolute.

The `tokenType` is an index into the token types legend, which is established during the initialization handshake of the protocol. The legend for the token modifiers is also established during the initialization handshake.

Although the `tokenModifiers` value above is just an integer, it will be interpreted as a bit vector, where each bit indicates whether the corresponding modifier is on or off. For example, the above assigns the first token (`foo`) the modifiers `0b11`, indicating that both the 0th and the 1st token modifier are active, and all other modifiers do not apply to this token.

Comment: Updated link: https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#textDocument_semanticTokens